# Extracting data from div tag

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

so im scraping data from a website and it has some data in its div tag
like this :

```
<div class="search-result__title">\nDonald Duck <span>\xa0|\xa0</span>\n<span class="city state" data-city="city, TX;city, TX;city, TX;city, TX" data-state="TX"><a href="https://example.com/" rel="nofollow">STATENAME, CITYNAME</a>\n</span>\n</div>,
```

I want to scrape "Donald Duck" part and state and city name after rel="nofollow"
the site contains a lot of data so name and state are different

the code that i have written is

```
div = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'search-result__title'})
print (div.string)
```

this gives me a error

```
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, use `.text`. Second, `find_all()` will return a list of elements. You need to specify the index value with either: `print (div[0].text)`, or since you will probably have more than 1 element, just iterate through them

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="search-result__title">\nDonald Duck <span>\xa0|\xa0</span>\n<span class="city state" data-city="city, TX;city, TX;city, TX;city, TX" data-state="TX"><a href="https://example.com/" rel="nofollow">STATENAME, CITYNAME</a>\n</span>\n</div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'search-result__title'})

print (div[0].text)


#OR


for each in div:
    print (each.text)
```